# Connection reset when adding <script></script> in CMS Block using Magento

Tags: magento-1.4, magento

When saving a CMS block in Magento 1.4.1, I am getting an error, **connection reinitalized** by my web browser.  I only get this this error, when adding the tags `<script></script>`.  Any other changes I can save and I can add new blocks as long as I don't use `<script></script>`

The only error I'm seeing is in /var/www/website/var/log/exception is this and only if I hit F5 after getting the connection reinitalized error.  Apache and other system logs are not reporting any additional errors.

```
2012-07-06T08:47:22+00:00 DEBUG (7): HEADERS ALREADY SENT: <pre>[0] 
/var/www/vhosts/site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php:44
    [1] /var/www/vhosts/site/lib/Zend/Controller/Response/Abstract.php:727
    [2] /var/www/vhosts/site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Response/Http.php:75
    [3] /var/www/vhosts/site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php:188
    [4] /var/www/vhosts/site/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php:304
    [5] /var/www/vhosts/site/app/Mage.php:596
    [6] /var/www/vhosts/site/index.php:78
```

This website was working fine on a Centos 5.4 with PHP 5.2.13.  All the same Apache and PHP modules were installed on the new Debian server.  Any help would be sincerely appreciated.

**Version Information**

Magento 1.4.1

Debian 6.0 i386

PHP 5.3.3-7+squeeze13 with Suhosin-Patch (cli) (built: Jun 10 2012 09:35:18) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2009 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
    with the ionCube PHP Loader v4.0.7, Copyright (c) 2002-2011, by ionCube Ltd.

Server version: Apache/2.2.16 (Debian)
Server built:   Apr  1 2012 06:40:08

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A rule in our Netasq firewall was blocking the `<SCRIPT>` tag.  Once we disabled the rule, the client was able to use the tag again.  We did warn him, however, that netasq probably put that rule their for a very good reason.